# Is it possible to adjust distance of any two points and skip some points on X Axis in BEMSimpleLineGraph?

Tags: objective-c, bemsimplelinegraph

Is it possible to use BEMSimpleLineGraph with some data point missing?
For example:
X Axis Time
Y Axis Temperature

10:00 67
11:00 70
12:00 Unknown
13:00 72
14:00 69

Connect 70 and 72 with double the X Axis distance between 10:00 and 11:00.
Drop the 12:00 point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding `BEMNULLGRAPHVALUE` as your unknown.

For your example, assuming that your Y values are CGFloats, that would yield the following:

```
10:00 67 11:00 70 12:00 BEMNULLGRAPHVALUE 13:00 72 14:00 69
```

This feature was first addressed in [Issue 104](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph/pull/104), and added with [Pull Request 132](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph/pull/132).